# My Image in S3 Not Show. What's Wrong?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, image-upload

I have Upload an image from my node js web to S3, with this code :

```
router.post('/uploadtest', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res, next) {

  var file = req.files.file;

   var data = {Key: file.originalFilename, Body: file.path, ContentType: file.type, ACL: 'public-read'};

    s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data) { 
      if (err) 
        { console.log('Failed!'); 
            res.redirect("/lookpic?url=null");
        } else { 
          console.log('Success!'); 
          var urls = 'https://'+sendurl+'.amazonaws.com/'+myBucket+'/'+file.originalFilename
          res.redirect("/lookpic?url="+urls);
        } 
    });
});
```

And it's work, my image stored to my S3 bucket, but When I click the link to see my image, this is the result :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAM5N.png

What's wrong with my step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just specifying the file path in the body attribute whereas the file data should be provided in body attribute. Try this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
router.post('/uploadtest', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res, next) {

    var file = req.files.file;
    var file_data = fs.readFileSynch(file.path);
    var data = {Key: file.originalFilename, Body: file_data, ContentType: file.type, ACL: 'public-read'};

    s3Bucket.putObject(data, function(err, data) { 
        if (err) 
          { console.log('Failed!'); 
          res.redirect("/lookpic?url=null");
        } else { 
          console.log('Success!'); 

          // remove the uploaded file if you want to
          fs.unlink(file.path, function(err) {
              if (err) throw err;
          });
         //

          var urls = 'https://'+sendurl+'.amazonaws.com/'+myBucket+'/'+file.originalFilename
          res.redirect("/lookpic?url="+urls);
        } 
    });
});
```

Use the fs module to synchronously read the file to be uploaded. Checkout this link: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html